# Hot reload not working in flutter when app is running on emulator android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, flutter

Flutter hot reload is not working even when app is already running on emulator in android studio,
I already tried invalid caches & restart,
Deleted and recreated emulator...

[image]

After running flutter clean & flutter doctor
[image: dded]

Still not able to hot reload...

Comment: maybe..  reason is build fail, no file variants found for asset

Comment: can you run flutter doctor in terminal? Please post the result here. You could also try running flutter clean in terminal

Comment: @Uni I have updated the post

Comment: @KaranMehta As suggested above, you should fixing the issues with the assets and that Flutter Doctor showed you. And then see if you still have issues and share them with us.